# Sending View Action To Specific Controller

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Currently I have an View in my application template that sends an event to the ApplicationController.  I really would rather just send it to the another controller, PlaylistController, directly from the View, but I can't figure out how.

This is my current ApplicationController

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  needs:['playlist'],
  changeSong: function(delta) {
    this.get('controllers.playlist').send('changeSong', delta);
  }
});
```

And this is the view, which is in the application template:

```
App.NextSong = Ember.View.extend({
  classNames: ['entypo', 'to-end'],
  tagName: 'a',
  click: function() {
    this.get('controller').send('changeSong', 1);
  }
});
```

Comment: In this specific case, can you just use `<a {{action changeSong target="controllers.otherController"}}>click</a>` ? You'd have to define your other controller under the `needs` property of whatever controller is in charge of the template.

Comment: that's most of the battle.  Follow-up question, is there any way to pass parameters to action?  I definitely could just write a next, prev method which passes -1, 1 to a changeSong method, but it would be nice to just pass -1, or 1 to changeSong, skipping those two other mentioned methods

Comment: hmm, I'm not sure about passing `number` values, but you can pass objects as context. `<a {{action actionName context}}>`. Check out the guide for this: http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/

Comment: yeah I've seen objects used, but it looks like you can't pass parameters.  I ended up just creating two methods that passed an int to changeSong.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copying my answer from the comments above.

In this specific case, you can use:

`<a {{action changeSong target="controllers.otherController"}}>click</a>`

You'll have to define your other controller under the `needs` property of whatever controller is in charge of the template.